# Jquery - SerializeArray() checkbox that is not "checked"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

so I am trying to implement the Jquery .serializeArray() method to transform a form into a JSON string to send it out in a request.  This works great for my form except for checkboxes and radio buttons.  The only time this works properly is when they are checked.  Sometimes, I need to know if they are unchecked.  They still need to get serialized.

I suppose I could manually loop through the form and grab the values and build the JSON object, but that would not be optimal.

According to the Jquery documentation found here:  [Jquery Docs](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/)  anything that fits the W3 standards for a successful control [found here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2) should get included.  Unfortunately, this does not include checkboxes that are not checked.  Does anyone have a work around for this behavior?  Thanks in advance...

---

```
var form = document.getElementById('f');
console.log($(form).serializeArray();
```

That spits out the serialized form with the checkboxes that are not checked excluded...

Comment: Similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029870/jquery-serialize-does-not-register-checkboxes

Comment: Lol, I do, but it's not very interesting.  Everything you need to know is up there.  I will update it though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I developed a workaround.

Basically I wrote a function to compare the original JSON object to the serialized form.  As I looped through, I compared the components.  If there was a discrepancy, I pulled the component off the form and manually inserted it into the JSON.  I used the `array.splice()` method to add the missing components.  Worked for all of the missing inputs.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use checkboxes and radio buttons, have those input fields update a corresponding hidden field. That way, the hidden input will always be sent.

Answer (score 3):

how about trying this, I had a similar problem, I thought unchecked checkboxes should have a value as well, here is a quick work around,
    add an extra class on each checkbox on your form "cbx"
    make data an array from the form with serialise

then loop through all checkboxes with a class of "cbx"
and add them to the array with a value of 0, AFTER the array has been created with (serializeArray())

when you post the data you will see the unchecked checboxes and values of 0 will get transferred with the post.

```
    var data = $('#form').serializeArray();

    $(".cbx:not(:checked)").each(function() {
        data.push({name: this.name, value: '0' });
    });

    $.post("testpage.asp", data);
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative would be to use a jQuery plugin. For example, [serializeJSON](https://github.com/marioizquierdo/jquery.serializeJSON) has the option to set the value for unchecked checkboxes like this:

```
$('form').serializeJSON({checkboxUncheckedValue: "false"});
```

In any case, it is usually best to use hidden inputs for unchecked values.