# Get proper checkbox value using form.serialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization

We are currently using `$('form').serialize()` to get all form information

This will return any checkbox values as "On" or "Off".

Is there any way to get a 1/0 or true/false value using this same method?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes. You can do it by adding a hidden input with the same name as checkbox which value will be submitted if checkbox is unchecked:

```
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="false"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="true"/>
```

It will submit both values if checkbox is checked. But server side will read the latest one (value of checkbox)

Comment: If you have many checkboxes, this method can get unwieldy. Here is a better approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7108685/399435

Comment: Absolutely disagree with you @KarthicRaghupathi. If multiline custom JS with non-transparent logic looks 'more wieldy' for you, just go for it. The original question was about binary values, not multiple. For me - two lines of html code is a much more elegant solution.

Comment: the other approach is also for binary values. Only it deals with all check boxes in the form. I had to deal with 20 checkboxes in a form. Your approach means 40 input tags as opposed to few lines of JS.

Comment: Some applications like EMRs/EHRs have large forms with lots of checkboxes. It may not necessarily mean bad UX.

Answer (score 1):

The value of a form control is always a string. You can use radio buttons to get different values for the same control name:

```
<form ...>
  <input type="radio" name="whatever" value="true">true
  <br>
  <input type="radio" name="whatever" value="false">false
  ...
</form>
```

Only one can be checked, and only the checked name/value will be sent to the server.

Answer (score 1):

If we have multiple checkboxed in our page like :

```
  <input id="reminder" name="Check1" value="false" type="checkbox" /> 

  <input id="alarm" name="Check2" value="false" type="checkbox" />
```

we have to bind the change event of these checkboxes and set its value to true or false.

```
 $('input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function(){
    var name =    $(this).attr('name');
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
    $('input[name= "' +name +'"]').val(true);
        $(this).val(true);
    }
    else{
       $(this).val(false);
       $('input[name= "' +name +'"]').val(false);
    }
});
```

By default, checkbox value doesn't appear in $('form').serializeArray(), It appears when it is checked.

We have to keep one hidden field for each checkbox like :

```
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="Check1" />
<input type="hidden" value="false" name="Check2" />
```

Now when we serialize the form now, we get the correct value like :
    Check1=true 
    Check2=false

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new class for check boxes and set value when clicked.

```
<input class="checkbox" id="someId" type="checkbox" value="false" />Checkbox
```

And use a small JQuery helper

```
$('.checkbox').click(function () {
    $(this).val() == "false" ? $(this).val("true") : $(this).val("false");
});
```

Then you will be able to get the value of the check box or serialize a form.

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="check1" value="true" id="check1">
```

just set the value

Comment: it's not gonna get updated if we check/uncheck the checkbox and needs more js to work