# setting custom initial value for indeterminate checkbox works only after clicking

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I've been working on implementing a tri-state checkbox based on the demo presented in this [CSS-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/) article. However, I did a small change where I also set the input value through `$(el).val()` so `0` is indeterminated and `1` is checked:

```
inputs.on('click.tristate', function () {
    el = $(this);
    switch (el.data('checked')) {

        // unchecked, going indeterminate
        case -1:
            el.data('checked', 0);
            el.val(0) 
            el.prop('indeterminate', true);
            break;

            // indeterminate, going checked
        case 0:
            el.data('checked', 1);
            el.val(1); 
            el.prop('indeterminate', false);
            el.prop('checked', true);
            break;

            // checked, going unchecked
        default:
            el.data('checked', -1);
            el.prop('indeterminate', false);
            el.prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```

This works as expected - when clicking it switches between states, and when you send the form, it sends indeterminate as 0 and checked as 1 (and unchecked it doesn't send at all).

Now I'm having trouble with setting the initial value. I've added this:

```
inputs.each(function () {
    if ($(this).data('checked') === 0) {
        this.indeterminate = true;
        this.value = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (this.checked) $(this).data('checked', 1);
    else              $(this).data('checked', -1);
});
```

It **works visually**, but if you run `$('form').serialize()` you see that it treats the indeterminate input as if it was unchecked (i.e., not adding it). If you click a few times, and do a full loop, it *does* add it. So what gives?

I've made a [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/d2v0o4qx/) to demonstrate the behavior. I tried many different ways to define the initial value, but I just can't seem to be able to make it treat the indeterminate field as something that needs to be added.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what I found about HTML attribute is a BUG > [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/d2v0o4qx/6/).

```
<input type="checkbox" name="cb2" value='0' data-checked='0' checked="false" class="tristate-checkbox" />
```

There is an [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029870/jquery-serialize-does-not-register-checkboxes) about your problem with checkbox value and serialize.

Normally serialize handle checkbox by a single way: checked = false equals no display and checked = true equals display something.

> jQuery serialize closely mimics how a standard form would be
>   serialized by the browser before being appended to the query string or
>   POST body in the request. Unchecked checkboxes aren't included by the
>   browser, which makes sense really because they have a boolean state

Comment: Yeah, of course I can loop on them all and build the query myself. But I **didn't ask how to do that and I don't want to anyway**. Besides - after clicking, `.serialize()` *does indeed recognize the custom value*. In other words, I want to stimulate that with the code so `serialize` will work out of the box (triggering click on the input doesn't work)

Comment: Well if your problem is initial statement look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/d2v0o4qx/6/). You missed arguments on your initializing phase.

Comment: Yes that's the answer I was looking for! how come `checked="false"` fixes this? I'd love a detailed explanation because I find this a bit puzzling to be truthful...

Comment: Well I guess serialize function need it. It looking for checked attribute. If this attribute is not here, it display nothing, if the attribute is here it interpret it. My hypothesis make sense :)

Comment: Only clicking doesn't add the `checked` attribute, and still causes the form to check the value. I'm thinking you're right though - the checked attribute is probably not set and that's the problem (however, setting `checked = false` [through the javascript](http://jsfiddle.net/yuvii/d2v0o4qx/7/) doesn't work so I'm even more confused...)

Comment: I guess what I found about HTML attribute is a BUG. Look at [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029870/jquery-serialize-does-not-register-checkboxes). There is an explanation about checkbox value and serialize. Normally serialize handle checkbox by a single way: checkek = false equals no display and checked = true equals display something

Comment: OK, that makes it a tad clearer. Anyway, update your answer with the relevant information and I'll mark it as correct