# Send the Boolean value to the controller via ajax commands at asp.net.core c#

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, model-view-controller

I have a form in the view section that has a checkbox type input

```html
<div class="checkbox">
<label class="">active</label>
<div class="icheckbox_flat-green checked" style="position: relative;">
<input type="checkbox" id="AdvActive" name="AdvActive" class="flat" checked="checked"/>
</div>                            
</div>
```

And through the ajax code below I send the values ​​to the controller

```html
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: '@Url.Action("CreateAdvBanner", "Advertise")',
  cache: false,
   data: form.serialize()
})
```

All form values ​​are sent to the controller except the same checkbox. Do I want to send "True" to the controller when the checkbox is checked?
This is my controller

```html
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult CreateAdvBanner(string AdvCode, int AdvPrice ,int AdvDay, string AdvDesc,bool AdvActive)
{
```

Comment: If you want to include the check box value you should send it explicitly.

Comment: Refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029870/jquery-serialize-does-not-register-checkboxes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery serialize does not register checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029870/jquery-serialize-does-not-register-checkboxes)

Answer (score 1):

Send JSON to controller

something like

```
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: '@Url.Action("CreateAdvBanner", "Advertise")',
  cache: false,
  data: {"AdvCode" : "itsValue", "AdvPrice":"itsValue", "AdvDay" : "itsValue", "AdvDesc" : "somevalue"}  
})
```

boolean values and numbers mustn't be in ""